# Excel worksheets merged side by side

Tags: excel, merge, worksheet

I need to merge all data from all worksheets into one single worksheet, horizontally aligned (side by side). All I could find is vertically aligned (on top of previous data set).

Thanks in advance for the support.

Update:

Each Excel file have 27 worksheets with 5 columns and 6000 lines each. The result would be one worksheet with 135 (5*27) columns and 6000 lines. After using Kutools plugin, I could achieve one worksheet with 162000 (6000*27) lines and 5 columns. The point is that I need those data side by side, not vertically aligned.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example? How many rows/columns in each, etc.

Comment: If they have a common reference point (e.g. ID) which I'm assuming they do, otherwise why would you want them side by side? Then use a `vlookup`

Comment: Description updated

Comment: I solved this with an external plugin. Thanks!